# Change JSON date format in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, date

I am assigning values from a `json` array to a form using the below `jquery` code:

```
$.getJSON('/mysite',function(result){
    $('.forminput').each(function(){
        $(this).val(result[this.id]);
    });
};
```

The array would looks like this and has a `date` format for 'birthday':

```
{name: 'John',
 address: 'here',
 birthday: ISODate("1974-10-27T16:00:00Z")}
```

I'd like to convert the date to `mm/dd/yyyy` format (otherwise it displays this: '2010-10-27T16:00:00.000Z'). My question is, what code can I insert to the client-side to convert the `date` value before assigning it, such as:

```
$.getJSON('/mysite',function(result){
    $('.forminput').each(function(){
        if(typeof result[this.id]== 'DATE'){
            result[this.id].format('mm/dd/yyyy'); 
            $(this).val(result[this.id]);
         }
        else{
        $(this).val(result[this.id]);             
        }
     }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a great idea to show the date you are talking about???

Comment: If you don't mind adding another library to your project I would suggest using moment js. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @MaxBaldwin What does momentjs provide in this case that cannot be done with a Data object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new Date object on your iso date string with:

```
var dateString = "2010-10-27T16:00:00.000Z";
var d = new Date(dateString);
```

You can then access the various methods of the date object and construct what ever string you need. e.g.

```
var result = (d.getMonth() +1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

That produces the result "10/27/2010".

You would need loop through your response and apply the above code to each of your iso date values.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in his original version of the JSON class the master himself, 
 Douglas Crockford, provided a way of "reviving" date objects in JSON objects, see [here](http://www.json.org/js.html):

```
// in: json_parse(text, reviver)
function reviver (key, value) {
 var a;
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
  a =
   /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?)Z$/.exec(value);
  if (a) {
   return new Date(Date.UTC(+a[1], +a[2] - 1, +a[3], +a[4], +a[5], +a[6]));
   }
  }
  return value;
}
```

The function `reviver` can be inserted as a second argument of the `JSON.parse()` function and will only step into action if an ISO date string is identified.

To insert the date object with your specified formatting into your form you could use something like this:

```
Date.prototype.fmtUS=function(){
 var dd=function(i){return (i<10?'0':'')+i;};
 return dd(this.getMonth()+1)+'/'+dd(this.getDate())+'/'+this.getFullYear();};

new Date().fmtUS() // "08/29/2015"
```

If you want to go a step further you could also make your `fmtUS()` the standard date format by doing

```
with(Date.prototype)toString=fmtUS;
new Date(); // "08/29/2015"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
$.getJSON('/mysite',function(result){
    $('.forminput').each(function(){
        if (this.id==='birthday'){
            console.log('result[this.id]: '+result[this.id]);
            var bday=convertdate(result[this.id]);
            console.log(bday);
            $(this).val(bday);
        }
        else{
            $(this).val(result[this.id]);// assigns each key value to each element id.
        }
```

and the convertdate function:

```
function convertdate(dtvalue){
        console.log('converting date')
        var datestring = new Date(dtvalue);
        var d=new Date(datestring);
        return result = (d.getMonth() +1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}
```